# Passphrase in a script

Tags: gnupg, seahorse

I am trying to decrypt the content of a gEdit tab using an external script. My script is
based on this article: http://blog.brunobraga.net/encrypting-and-decrypting-with-gedit/

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
stdin=$(cat)

if [ "${stdin:0:27}" == "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----"  ]; then 
    echo "$stdin" | gpg -d --no-tty - 2> /dev/null
else
    echo "$stdin"
fi
```

My private key has a passphrase. When I invoke the decryption script it fails because I am not supplying the passphrase.

How do I change the script so that I get the passphrase prompt?

Comment: Interestingly, for me it works without problems. Can you please add the error message?

Comment: @A.B.  It doesn't show any error message. But I also don't get results. I get the correct result when I decrypt from command line.

Comment: Which GUI you use?

Comment: @A.B. I am using Seahorse on Linux Mint for key management. The script is tried as an extension command in gEdit.

Comment: You shouldn't discard stderr when debugging a problem. Maybe also consider using GnuPG 2 (executable `gpg2`), which will invoke `gpg-agent` and can prompt for the passphrase in a GUI window.

Comment: I got the same error with `gpg2` and without  `-no-tty - 2> /dev/null`